# Templates and matrix transformations

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, transformation

Before I ask the question:

1. While the code uses the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) library, the question isn't about that particular library
2. While typical rotation matrices are 3x3, the matrices below are 4x4 (use homogeneous coordinates) for graphics programming.

So, with that out of the way...

Rotation matrices about the X, Y and Z axes can be computed with the following functions, respectively:

```
Eigen::Matrix4f rotateX(float angle) {
    float radianAngle = radians(angle);
    float Sin = sinf(radianAngle);
    float Cos = cosf(radianAngle);

    Eigen::Matrix4f rotationMatrix( Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity() );

    rotationMatrix(1, 1) =  Cos;
    rotationMatrix(1, 2) =  Sin;
    rotationMatrix(2, 1) = -Sin;
    rotationMatrix(2, 2) =  Cos;

    return rotationMatrix;
}

Eigen::Matrix4f rotateY(float angle) {
    float radianAngle = radians(angle);
    float Sin = sinf(radianAngle);
    float Cos = cosf(radianAngle);

    Eigen::Matrix4f rotationMatrix( Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity() );

    rotationMatrix(0, 0) =  Cos;
    rotationMatrix(0, 2) =  Sin;
    rotationMatrix(2, 0) = -Sin;
    rotationMatrix(2, 2) =  Cos;

    return rotationMatrix;
}

Eigen::Matrix4f rotateZ(float angle) {
    float radianAngle = radians(angle);
    float Sin = sinf(radianAngle);
    float Cos = cosf(radianAngle);

    Eigen::Matrix4f rotationMatrix( Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity() );

    rotationMatrix(0, 0) =  Cos;
    rotationMatrix(0, 1) =  Sin;
    rotationMatrix(1, 0) = -Sin;
    rotationMatrix(1, 1) =  Cos;

    return rotationMatrix;
}
```

These functions are very similar; as you can see, the only difference is in indexing the matrix. These implementations are also present in the [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net) headers.

Is there a way to express these three functions as one, maybe using templates, without added run-time overhead?

Any comments on the code are welcome.

Comment: You probably intend the Y rotation matrix to have opposite signs on the `sin` elements, in order to preserve right-hand conventions on your rotations.  Assuming a right-hand coordinate system, that is.

Comment: @Peter good point! I think I'm going to keep it like this, though, because the question is about templates, more than the transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
enum Axis {X, Y, Z};

// in C++14 you can just use std::max and std::min instead
constexpr int mymax(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
constexpr int mymin(int a, int b) { return a < b ? a : b; }

template <Axis axis>
Eigen::Matrix4f rotateAxis(float angle) {
    float radianAngle = radians(angle);
    float Sin = sinf(radianAngle);
    float Cos = cosf(radianAngle);

    Eigen::Matrix4f rotationMatrix( Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity() );

    constexpr int c1 = mymin((axis + 1) % 3, (axis + 2) % 3);
    constexpr int c2 = mymax((axis + 1) % 3, (axis + 2) % 3);

    rotationMatrix(c1, c1) =  Cos;
    rotationMatrix(c1, c2) =  Sin;
    rotationMatrix(c2, c1) = -Sin;
    rotationMatrix(c2, c2) =  Cos;

    return rotationMatrix;
}
```

Comment: That looks good. Do you mind commenting on the readability of the answer vs the code in the question? Which would you go for, and why?

Comment: @Nasser as for me, it looks fine. Note that if you take into account Peter's comment, the code will become even simpler, without need of `max` and `min` functions (like I wrote in the very first edition of the answer).